# Not able to create Node Express project in Eclipse Luna with Nodeclipse installed

Tags: node.js, eclipse, express, eclipse-luna, nodeclipse

I am not able to create a NodeJS + Express project with the complete project structure as shown in various discussion boards and tutorial videos in Eclipse Luna.

Following are the details of my system, Node and Nodeclipse configuration.

1. Windows 10 Pro 64 Bit
2. Eclipse Luna
3. JRE 1.8_77
4. System Environment Variable - Path=D:\ProgramFiles\nodejs\
5. System Environment Variable - NODE_PATH=D:\ProgramFiles\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules
6. User Environment Variable - Path=D:\ProgramFiles\nodejs\node_modules\npm
7. In Eclipse>Preferences>Nodeclipse I have set

   - Express Path = D:\ProgramFiles\nodejs\node_modules\npm\express
   - Coffee Path = D:\ProgramFiles\nodejs\node_modules\npm\coffee
8. I have tried running Eclipse in Administrator mode too. That hasn't helped.

The result of npm config ls -l is as below,

```
    ; cli configs
    long = true
    user-agent = "npm/3.9.5 node/v6.2.2 win32 x64"

    ; userconfig C:\Users\SomeName\.npmrc
    prefix = "D:\\ProgramFiles\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm"

    ; builtin config undefined
    ; prefix = "C:\\Users\\SomeName\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm" (overridden)

    ; default values
    access = null
    also = null
    always-auth = false
    bin-links = true
    browser = null
    ca = null
    cache = "C:\\Users\\SomeName\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm-cache"
    cache-lock-retries = 10
    cache-lock-stale = 60000
    cache-lock-wait = 10000
    cache-max = null
    cache-min = 10
    cafile = undefined
    cert = null
    color = true
    depth = null
    description = true
    dev = false
    dry-run = false
    editor = "notepad.exe"
    engine-strict = false
    fetch-retries = 2
    fetch-retry-factor = 10
    fetch-retry-maxtimeout = 60000
    fetch-retry-mintimeout = 10000
    force = false
    git = "git"
    git-tag-version = true
    global = false
    global-style = false
    globalconfig = "D:\\ProgramFiles\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\etc\\npmrc"
    globalignorefile = "D:\\ProgramFiles\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\etc\\npmignore"
    group = 0
    heading = "npm"
    https-proxy = null
    if-present = false
    ignore-scripts = false
    init-author-email = ""
    init-author-name = ""
    init-author-url = ""
    init-license = "ISC"
    init-module = "C:\\Users\\SomeName\\.npm-init.js"
    init-version = "1.0.0"
    json = false
    key = null
    legacy-bundling = false
    link = false
    local-address = undefined
    loglevel = "warn"
    ; long = false (overridden)
    maxsockets = 50
    message = "%s"
    node-version = "6.2.2"
    npat = false
    onload-script = null
    only = null
    optional = true
    parseable = false
    ; prefix = "D:\\ProgramFiles\\nodejs" (overridden)
    production = false
    progress = true
    proprietary-attribs = true
    proxy = null
    rebuild-bundle = true
    registry = "https://registry.npmjs.org/"
    rollback = true
    save = false
    save-bundle = false
    save-dev = false
    save-exact = false
    save-optional = false
    save-prefix = "^"
    scope = ""
    searchexclude = null
    searchopts = ""
    searchsort = "name"
    shell = "C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\cmd.exe"
    shrinkwrap = true
    sign-git-tag = false
    strict-ssl = true
    tag = "latest"
    tag-version-prefix = "v"
    tmp = "C:\\Users\\SOME~1.NAM\\AppData\\Local\\Temp"
    umask = 0
    unicode = false
    unsafe-perm = true
    usage = false
    user = 0
    ; user-agent = "npm/{npm-version} node/{node-version} {platform} {arch}" (overridden)
    userconfig = "C:\\Users\\SomeName\\.npmrc"
    version = false
    versions = false
    viewer = "browser"
```

Following is the exception that I am receiving when I create a NodeJS Express Project in the NodeJS perspective,

```
    java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at org.nodeclipse.ui.util.ProcessUtils.exec(ProcessUtils.java:202)
        at org.nodeclipse.ui.wizards.ExpressProjectWizard.generateExpressApplication(ExpressProjectWizard.java:231)
        at org.nodeclipse.ui.wizards.ExpressProjectWizard.access$1(ExpressProjectWizard.java:199)
        at org.nodeclipse.ui.wizards.ExpressProjectWizard$2.run(ExpressProjectWizard.java:122)
        at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:122)
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "" (in directory "C:\Users\SOME~1.NAM\AppData\Local\Temp\express-work\1468060211358"): CreateProcess error=87, The parameter is incorrect
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
        at org.nodeclipse.ui.util.ProcessUtils.exec(ProcessUtils.java:184)
        ... 4 more
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=87, The parameter is incorrect
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
        ... 6 more
    Root exception:
    java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "" (in directory "C:\Users\SOME~1.NAM\AppData\Local\Temp\express-work\1468060211358"): CreateProcess error=87, The parameter is incorrect
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
        at org.nodeclipse.ui.util.ProcessUtils.exec(ProcessUtils.java:184)
        at org.nodeclipse.ui.wizards.ExpressProjectWizard.generateExpressApplication(ExpressProjectWizard.java:231)
        at org.nodeclipse.ui.wizards.ExpressProjectWizard.access$1(ExpressProjectWizard.java:199)
        at org.nodeclipse.ui.wizards.ExpressProjectWizard$2.run(ExpressProjectWizard.java:122)
        at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:122)
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=87, The parameter is incorrect
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
        ... 6 more
```